# How to exit SLIME - comma or quit not working

Tags: emacs, common-lisp, slime

I'm am trying to use SLIME in Emacs.

When in the SLIME REPL, inputting `,` (comma) ends up in the error

```
Comma not inside a backquote.
```

Inputting `quit` instead end up in

```
The variable QUIT is unbound.
```

Simple question then: how do I exit SLIME? What's the problem in my case?

Answer (score 3):

Found the reason.

I was not using the `slime-fancy` metapackage, which allows you to use additional facilities from the Contributed Packages of SLIME.

I just added:

```lisp
(slime-setup '(slime-fancy))
```

to my emacs init file.

Info on SLIME Contributed Packages at: https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/UNOFFICIAL/docs/slime/doc/Loading-Contribs.html#Loading-Contribs